# API unable to fetch temperature

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

I want to show the temperature from ma current location.

I have put my files on the server; unblocked the location on GoogleChrome.

I have subscribed to OpenWeatherMap and copy paste the correct apiKey and I do still have this error: Unable to fetch temperature

Here is the error message from my console log:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
>
> GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=pastenumber&lon=pastenumber&units=metric&appid=YOUR_API_KEY net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
>
> Error fetching weather data: TypeError: Failed to fetch at script.js:9:34

Here is the script.js :

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const latitude = pastenumber; 
    const longitude = pastenumber; 
    const apiKey = 'pasteNumberFromOpenWeatherMapApp';
  
    const apiUrl = `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apiKey}&q=${latitude},${longitude}`;
  
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Weather data not available');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        const temperature = data.current.temp_c;
        console.log(`Current Temperature: ${temperature}°C`);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching weather data:', error);
      });
  });
```

I am expecting to get the temperature of my current location.

Comment: Does it work locally before you put it on the server, and are you sure that is the correct api? I use openweathermap and the api I call is the one from your error message `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather`, not your `apiUrl`

Comment: You're not online `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`